# Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process D:\SSB\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\2

Tags: android, debugging

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.  Errors inside image:

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

Comment: You should tell, what have you done.